# excel to csv using visual studio

Tags: excel, vba, visual-studio, csv

I'm trying to convert my excel file to csv using visual studio and I'm having trouble converting it. I have looped my code to go through .xls or .xlsx file in a folder and convert each one of them to csv. However, I'm having no results at all :(

Textbox1.Text is the folder selected and Textbox2.Text is the destination folder. 
Anyone can help me on this?

Here is my code:

```
Dim xls As Excel.Application
Dim strFile As String, strPath As String

xls = New Excel.Application
strPath = TextBox1.Text
strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls")

While strFile <> ""
  xls.Workbooks.Open(strPath & strFile)
  xls.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(Filename:=Replace(TextBox2.Text & strFile, ".xls", ".csv"), FileFormat:=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlTextMSDOS)
  xls.Workbooks.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close(SaveChanges:=False)

  strFile = Dir()
End While

xls.Quit()
```

Comment: What happens when you run it? Does it crash? Or there are no files?

Comment: There are no files...

Comment: Maybe put a break and check the values of strPath and strFile? Break inside the While to see if it enters it at all. Or try saving with hardcoded path to see if it works.

Comment: side note `xls.Workbooks.Application` is the same as `xls`

Answer (score 1):

Put this inside a text file and save it as `Excel2Csv.vbs`. Save it inside a folder containing all your excel files. Then just simply drag your excel files onto this .vbs file.

```
'* Usage: Drop .xl* files on me to export each sheet as CSV

'* Global Settings and Variables
Dim gSkip
Set args = Wscript.Arguments

For Each sFilename In args
    iErr = ExportExcelFileToCSV(sFilename)
    ' 0 for normal success
    ' 404 for file not found
    ' 10 for file skipped (or user abort if script returns 10)
Next

WScript.Quit(0)

Function ExportExcelFileToCSV(sFilename)
    '* Settings
    Dim oExcel, oFSO, oExcelFile
    Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    iCSV_Format = 6

    '* Set Up
    sExtension = oFSO.GetExtensionName(sFilename)
    if sExtension = "" then
        ExportExcelFileToCSV = 404
        Exit Function
    end if
    sTest = Mid(sExtension,1,2) '* first 2 letters of the extension, vb's missing a Like operator
    if not (sTest =  "xl") then
        if (PromptForSkip(sFilename,oExcel)) then
            ExportExcelFileToCSV = 10
            Exit Function
        end if
    End If
    sAbsoluteSource = oFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(sFilename)
    sAbsoluteDestination = Replace(sAbsoluteSource,sExtension,"{sheet}.csv")

    '* Do Work
    Set oExcelFile = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(sAbsoluteSource)
    For Each oSheet in oExcelFile.Sheets
        sThisDestination = Replace(sAbsoluteDestination,"{sheet}",oSheet.Name)
        oExcelFile.Sheets(oSheet.Name).Select
        oExcelFile.SaveAs sThisDestination, iCSV_Format
    Next

    '* Take Down
    oExcelFile.Close False
    oExcel.Quit

    ExportExcelFileToCSV = 0
    Exit Function
End Function

Function PromptForSkip(sFilename,oExcel)
    if not (VarType(gSkip) = vbEmpty) then
        PromptForSkip = gSkip
        Exit Function
    end if

    Dim oFSO
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    sPrompt = vbCRLF & _
        "A filename was received that doesn't appear to be an Excel Document." & vbCRLF & _
        "Do you want to skip this and all other unrecognized files?  (Will only prompt this once)" & vbCRLF & _
        "" & vbCRLF & _
        "Yes    - Will skip all further files that don't have a .xl* extension" & vbCRLF & _
        "No     - Will pass the file to excel regardless of extension" & vbCRLF & _
        "Cancel - Abort any further conversions and exit this script" & vbCRLF & _
        "" & vbCRLF & _
        "The unrecognized file was:" & vbCRLF & _
        sFilename & vbCRLF & _
        "" & vbCRLF & _
        "The path returned by the system was:" & vbCRLF & _
        oFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(sFilename) & vbCRLF

    sTitle = "Unrecognized File Type Encountered"

    sResponse =  MsgBox (sPrompt,vbYesNoCancel,sTitle)
    Select Case sResponse
    Case vbYes
        gSkip = True
    Case vbNo
        gSkip = False
    Case vbCancel
        oExcel.Quit
        WScript.Quit(10)    '*  10 Is the error code I use to indicate there was a user abort (1 because wasn't successful, + 0 because the user chose to exit)
    End Select

    PromptForSkip = gSkip
    Exit Function
End Function
```